# Django, Heroku, DisallowedHost at / but host is in allowed hosts lists

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django app deployed to Heroku but when I try to visit it I get disallowed, hosts error saying that the Heroku host URL is not in the allowed host but it actually is.

The error

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'scr-rivendell.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add 'scr-rivendell.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1:8000', 'https://scr-rivendell.herokuapp.com/']
```

I checked in the shell to make sure I'm right:

```
>>> import django
>>> django.conf.settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS
['localhost', '127.0.0.1:8000', 'https://scr-rivendell.herokuapp.com/']
```

Comment: You need to get rid of https:// from there

Answer (score 0):

Url Scheme such as `http://` pr `https://` aren't a part of host address.

Updating your ALLOWED_HOSTS to below should work.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1:8000', 'scr-rivendell.herokuapp.com']
```